# Understanding iptables ICMP log

Tags: iptables, logging

I am studing IPTABLES and yesterday I was visiting a company and to connect to their network I had to turn of my firewall.

It was assigned the local IP to my wireless interface. I got this logs a few times while I was there, and I would like to understand them.

So yesterday I got this LOG:

`Feb 14 14:10:55 localhost kernel: [131988.098112] iptablesIP IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.245 DST=192.168.0.245 LEN=88 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=64 ID=39913 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=3 CODE=1 [SRC=192.168.0.245 DST=192.168.0.218 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=21366 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=55458 DPT=8009 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 ]`

Today I noticed that I am still getting this kind of log, but now with an external IP:

`Feb 15 08:39:15 localhost kernel: [155744.166284] iptablesIP IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=5c:c9:d3:31:e8:84:00:04:df:d8:40:05:08:00 SRC=147.75.70.44 DST=192.168.1.42 LEN=576 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=49 ID=48088 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=3 CODE=4 [SRC=192.168.1.42 DST=147.75.70.44 LEN=1492 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x40 TTL=43 ID=5197 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=26264 DPT=80 WINDOW=229 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 ] MTU=1480`

Can someone help me to understand what means?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

ICMP type 3 is "Destination Unreachable". So apparently, your PC attempted to contact 192.168.0.218 ( local on their net) yesterday and 147.75.70.44 today. We are even told about the ports: Yesterday it was [port 8009](https://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=8009) (most likely some "alternative" HTTP) and today port 80 (most certainly standard HTTP). The IP 147.75.70.44 seems to be alive and serve www.nielsen.com

As to *why* your PC would attempt to surf these hosts or why they were not reached, the ICMP message tells us nothing ...